# In spark dataframe for map column how to update values with a constant for all keys

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have spark dataframe with two columns of type Integer and Map, I wanted to know best way to update the values for all the keys for map column.

With help of UDF, I am able to update the values

```scala
def modifyValues = (map_data: Map[String, Int]) => {
      val divideWith = 10
      map_data.mapValues( _ / divideWith)
    }
val modifyMapValues = udf(modifyValues)
df.withColumn("updatedValues", modifyMapValues($"data_map"))


scala> dF.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- data_map: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Sample data:

```
>val ds = Seq(
  (1, Map("foo" -> 100, "bar" -> 200)),
  (2, Map("foo" -> 200)),
  (3, Map("bar" -> 200))
).toDF("id", "data_map")

Expected output:
+---+-----------------------+
|id |data_map               |
+---+-----------------------+
|1  |[foo -> 10, bar -> 20] |
|2  |[foo -> 20]            |
|3  |[bar -> 1]             |
+---+-----------------------+
```

Wanted to know, is there anyway to do this without UDF?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible way how to do it (without UDF) is this one:

1. extract keys using `map_keys` to an array
2. extract values using `map_values` to an array
3. transform extracted values using `TRANSFORM` (available since Spark 2.4)
4. create back the map using `map_from_arrays`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{expr, map_from_arrays, map_values, map_keys}

ds
.withColumn("values", map_values($"data_map"))
.withColumn("keys", map_keys($"data_map"))
.withColumn("values_transformed", expr("TRANSFORM(values, v -> v/10)"))
.withColumn("data_map_transformed", map_from_arrays($"keys", $"values_transformed"))
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Wanted to know is there any higher order function which can be applied directly on map?

Comment: @S1989 I was thinking about `transform_values` but apparently it will be available since Spark 3.0: https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23940

Comment: At least in pyspark, `map_values` and `map_keys` return an _unordered_ arrays. That means that for pyspark, the key-value pairs could mix in the final map. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_values.html

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sp
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, FloatType, MapType
```

Add a new key with any value:

```
my_update_udf = sp.udf(lambda x: {**x, **{'new_key':77}}, MapType(StringType(), FloatType()))
sdf = sdf.withColumn('updated', my_update_udf(sp.col('to_be_updated')))
```

Update value for all/one key(s):

```
my_update_udf = sp.udf(lambda x: {k:v/77) for k,v in x.items() if v!=None and k=='my_key'}, MapType(StringType(), FloatType()))
sdf = sdf.withColumn('updated', my_update_udf(sp.col('to_be_updated')))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way available in Spark 3:

```scala
  Seq(
    Map("keyToUpdate" -> 11, "someOtherKey" -> 12),
    Map("keyToUpdate" -> 21, "someOtherKey" -> 22)
  ).toDF("mapColumn")
    .withColumn(
      "mapColumn",
      map_concat(
        map(lit("keyToUpdate"), col("mapColumn.keyToUpdate") * 10), // <- transformation 
        map_filter(col("mapColumn"), (k, _) => k =!= "keyToUpdate")
      )
    )
    .show(false)
```

output:

```
+----------------------------------------+
|mapColumn                               |
+----------------------------------------+
|{someOtherKey -> 12, keyToUpdate -> 110}|
|{someOtherKey -> 22, keyToUpdate -> 210}|
+----------------------------------------+
```

[map_filter(expr, func)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map_filter) - Filters entries in a map using the function

[map_concat(map, ...)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map_concat) - Returns the union of all the given maps