# How to change value in a Map Datatype

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe having a column of type `MapType<StringType, StringType>`.

```
 |-- identity: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Identity column contains a key "update".

```
+-------------+
identity      |
+-------+-----+
[update  -> Y]|
[update  -> Y]|
[update  -> Y]|
[update  -> Y]|
+-------+-----+
```

How do I change the value of key "update" from "Y" to "N"?

I'm using spark version 2.3

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In spark dataframe for map column how to update values with a constant for all keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803864/in-spark-dataframe-for-map-column-how-to-update-values-with-a-constant-for-all-k)

Comment: @HosseinTorabi I'm using Spark 2.3. Unfortunately the methods suggested use functions available in version 2.4+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, in spark 2.3 there are no built in function to handle maps. The only way is probably to design a UDF:

```scala
val df = Seq(Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4), Map(7 -> 8, 1 -> 6)).toDF("m")
// a function that sets the value "new" to all key equal to "1"
val fun = udf((m : Map[String, String]) => 
    m.map{ case (key, value) => (key, if (key == "1") "new" else value) }
)
df.withColumn("m", fun('m)).show(false)
```

```
+------------------+
|m                 |
+------------------+
|{1 -> new, 3 -> 4}|
|{7 -> 8, 1 -> new}|
+------------------+
```

**JSON solution**

One alternative is to explode the map, make the updates and re aggregate it. Unfortunately, there is no way in spark 2.3 to create a map from a dynamic number of items. You could however aggregate the map as a json dictionary and then use the `from_json` function. I am pretty sure the first solution would be more efficient, but who knows. In pyspark, this solution might be faster than the UDF though.

```scala
df
    .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)
    .select($"id", explode('m))
    .withColumn("value", when('key === "1" ,lit("new")).otherwise('value))
    .withColumn("entry", concat(lit("\""), 'key, lit("\" : \""), 'value, lit("\"")))
    .groupBy("id").agg( collect_list('entry) as "list")
    .withColumn("json", concat(lit("{"), concat_ws(",", 'list), lit("}")))
    .withColumn("m", from_json('json, MapType(StringType, StringType)))
    .show(false)
```

Which yields the same result as before.